# NSString gets corrupted, changes to NSPrincipalClass

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsstring

I have an `NSDragOperation` that gets a property lists path upon the user dragging it into the window. That seems to work just fine, and I can save the path information to an NSString:

```
NString *thisPath = draggedFilePath;
NSLog(@" %@",thisPath);
```

> ```
> output: 2014-02-09 09:19:46.072 app[5944:303] /Users/Me/Desktop/file.plist
> ```

The problem starts when I go into a dispatch queue. When I try and read the NSString from inside the background queue the output becomes `NSPrincipalClass`. Does anyone know why this is happening, or if I'm supposed to convert the NSString to some other format before entering `dispatch_queue_t`?

```
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        });
    }

    NSLog(@" %@",thisPath);
```

> ```
>    output: 2014-02-09 09:19:56.234 app[5944:12203] NSPrincipalClass
> ```

EDIT: the output of the string using NSLog inside dispatch queue turns up random symbols, and also crashes. The last output was `<__NSMallocBlock__: 0x55a860>` - I have other strings that seem to be just fine within the same function, so I really don't know what is causing this.

Comment: Try making a copy of the string.

Answer (score 1):

one of three things is happening...

1. it is being deallocated, and a new object is being allocated in its place... you can try zombies...
2. it is getting assigned to a garbage value ie. draggedFilePath isn't ever initialized to zero, and isn't set to a good value.
3. your stack is getting smashed and it just happens to be there when it crashes... this is the hardest to find.

you are going to have to turn on zombies, the exception breakpoint and just step through it in the debugger... if that fails you get to either run in instruments with the malloc tool or turn on malloc history logging.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. It makes sense as to you've mentioned. A couple of questions I have: what's the best way to initialize draggedFilePath to zero; regarding zombies - if you could point me to something that might be useful that would be great since i'm unfamiliar.

Answer (score -1):

Does it work if you prefix the declaration of `thisPath` with `__block'? Like this:

```
__block NString *thisPath = draggedFilePath;
```

Comment: when i use `__block` the app crashes upon trying to nslog in dispatch queue. `libobjc.A.dylib objc_msgSend_vtable5:` `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x18)`

Comment: It's quite odd — I'm almost tempted to say that NSLog itself has something to do with it crashing.

Comment: What about if you retain the string?

Comment: same thing unfortunately.